# Disable the case sensitivity in Linux server

Tags: linux, case-sensitive

I have an app that shows some videos, some of them have capital letters extensions and the app requests the video as they have small letters extensions
Is there any way to make ".mp4" equals ".MP4" ? 
so when the app looks for ".MP4" the video which has ".mp4" will be played

Comment: ... Any specific app, or should we just take random guesses?

Comment: whatever! the programming has only one way to describe this case.. I mean anything you do in Android you also can do it in iOS .. Btw it's android app.. I can check the file before streaming the video but if I solved it in the server side it will be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution .. You've to create .htaccess file and put it inside the videos' folder

```
 <IfModule mod_speling.c>
    CheckSpelling On
    CheckCaseOnly On
 </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably going to want to modify the app to handle files in a case insensitive way rather than try and make your server case insensitive like Windows.

Comment: I think I can make it like put .htaccess file.. but I don't remember the solution

Answer (score 1):

The handling of the case insensitive case would be the onus of the application. There are library routines which could help in adding the case insensitive scenario in the application.

Alternatively, you could write a simple bash script to convert the extension.

```
for file in *.MP4; 
do
    mv $file `basename $file .MP4`.mp4
done
```